# checking for nullability before assigning to array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have multiple destination arrays defined and reading multiple source arrays and adding them to the destination array in my angular 4 application. I need to check for nullability before adding them as getting an error.

Destination arrays

```
public remainingCapInsPremiumPaid: number[] = [];
  public remainingCapTaxDeduction: number[] = [];
  public remainingCapLoanToParent: number[] = [];
  public remainingCapContribution: number[] = [];
  public remainingCapDividenedDistribution: number[] = [];
  public remainingCapTerminalValue: number[] = [];
  public remainingCaptNetCost: number[] = [];
  public remainingCommPremiumPaid: number[] = [];
  public remainingCommTaxDeduction: number[] = [];
  public remainingCommNetCost: number[] = [];
  public remainingSelfDiscountedLossesPaid: number[] = [];
  public remainingSelfDiscountedTaxDeduction: number[] = [];
  public remainingSelfNetCost: number[] = [];
```

reading source and assigning to destination

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.totalYears; i++) {
      // if the years exceed 7 then store the values in the remaining array list to display under the remaining section
      if (i > 6) {


this.remainingCapInsPremiumPaid.push(this.NpvResults.captiveInsPremiumPaid[i]);
    this.remainingCapTaxDeduction.push(this.NpvResults.captiveInsTaxDeduction[i]);
    this.remainingCapLoanToParent.push(this.NpvResults.captiveInsLoanToParent[i]);
    this.remainingCapContribution.push(this.NpvResults.captiveInsCapitalContribution[i]);
    this.remainingCapDividenedDistribution.push(this.NpvResults.captiveDividentDistribution[i]);
    this.remainingCapTerminalValue.push(this.NpvResults.captiveInsTerminalValue[i]);
    this.remainingCaptNetCost.push(this.NpvResults.captiveInsNetCost[i]);
    this.remainingCommPremiumPaid.push(this.NpvResults.captiveInsPremiumPaid[i]);
    this.remainingCommTaxDeduction.push(this.NpvResults.commInsTaxDeduction[i]);
    this.remainingCommNetCost.push(this.NpvResults.commInsNetCost[i]);
    this.remainingSelfDiscountedLossesPaid.push(this.NpvResults.selfInsDiscountedLossesPaid[i]);
    this.remainingSelfDiscountedTaxDeduction.push(this.NpvResults.selfInsDiscountedTaxDeduction[i]);
    this.remainingSelfNetCost.push(this.NpvResults.selfInsNetCost[i]);
  }
```

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: I am getting error read property '7' of null. When i debug , i can see its the 7th index in the array and the array is null

Comment: This line is erroring out this.NpvResults.captiveInsNetCost[i]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually check each array for null like so,

```
if(this.NpvResults.captiveInsPremiumPai !== null) {
  // write your logic here
}
```

Comment: How is it used in my context. I am a novice in javascript

Comment: I changed my answer because the `map` property which returned an empty array when it receives a null array was removed by the JS community.

You will have to use the above described method.

Answer (score 0):

Before pushing any value you need to check all `source` arrays for nullable and if their size is not smaller than the current index, put this check on all arrays:

```
if(this.NpvResults.sourceArray && this.NpvResults.sourceArray.length>i) 
    this.destinationArray.push(this.NpvResults.sourceArray[i]);
```

What this does is it checks if the `source array` is not `null` and if it's `length` is not smaller than the index, because if it is then you will get `Index out of bounds` exception